# Struts 2 result type redirectAction forward to wild card action method

Tags: java, struts2

My action class contains following action methods:

```
public class MyActionClass extends ActionSupport {

 public String valid(){
//
}

 public String invalid(){
//
}

}
```

My configurations:

```
<action name="*MyActionClass" class="action.MyActionClass" method="{1}">
            <interceptor-ref name="token"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
            <result type="chain" name="invalid.token" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">MyActionClass</param>
                <param name="method">invalid</param>
            </result>
            <result name="Completed">/example/valid.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

My forward to invalid.token result is not working. I'm trying to forward to action method within same action class.

It gives me Infinite recursion detected exception, which is i guess it's getting invalid.token again and again, can i disable token interceptor for this forward?

Comment: wildcard usage is the culprit here, due to which the same interceptors stack is used on redirect and hence, goes to infinite recursion.

Comment: This will result in `invalid.configuration` token.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following options ought to work:

1. (Preferred option) Redirect to another action class instead. Let the interceptor not be applied to that action class.
2. Within your `TokenInterceptor`, you can check if it is an invalid token based on the parameters:

   ```
   Map params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
   if (params.containsKey("method") && params.get("method").equals("invalid")){
      invocation.invoke(); //Pass on the invocation 
   } else {
      //Do your interceptor logic here
   }
   ```